Problem with using SSH on my server
I've been using PuTTY on a Windows machine to access the Ubuntu Server 22.04 I have running in my garage for a few months now. I've had no issues at all. I started using DirectAdmin on that server the other day for some management tasks and suddenly my SSH no longer works. I've tried uninstalling SSH from the server and reinstalling it, disabled the firewall to check that it wasn't a UFW problem, attempted to forward the port and connect from outside of my local network, and flushed DNS on the client side. I am totally lost and I've got no idea what to try next. I use this server commercially, so convenient access is super important. I always get a Network error: Connection timed out error on PuTTY.

Haha good point, sorry. I tagged the post with server but forgot to mention its running 22.04. Thanks.

Does ping -c2 garage.local or whatever is the hostname of your server work from Windows?

@user68186 If I try to ssh the localhost it works fine. It seems to just be an issue when doing it from this Windows machine. I've used both the local IP and a hostname but neither is working.

@user68186 I just tried to ping too, no dice. All pings lost.

@user68186 It is plugged in via ethernet and is accessible through my network manager though. I can't ping it, I can't access it, but both devices are connected over the same network and the ssh server works fine so long as I only try and access it over localhost. It just doesn't make sense to me...

@user68186 It is static and I have the correct address.

If you have found and fixed the issue please use the answer your own question button at the bottom of the question and make this an answer.

This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer inside the question (and SOLVED in the question title). Click on the Answer your own question button below and write a detailed answer for others. Then after the mandatory wait time, click on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green. This will mark your answer as correct and help others.

It was a firewall problem. DirectAdmin installed CSF firewall, but the asker thought the server only had UFW installed instead of CSF firewall which was blocking the SSH connection.
